# New Object Creation issues

Tags: javascript, object, this

Ok so the following function acts as a constructor to create an Employee object(no problem with that). But when I use this function to create 3 new employees I am messing up somewhere.

I know I'm supposed to set the properties and print the employee's name and phone number, but I am missing something or something is in the wrong place.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
  function Employe() {
    var = name;
    var = phone;
    this.getName = function () {
      return this.name;
    }
    this.setName = function (name, phone) {
      this.name = name;
      this.phone = phone;
    };
  }

  var emp1 = newEmployee;
  this.Name = 'jo';
  this.Phone = ' 555-5551'  
  document.write(Employee.name Employee.phone);

  var emp2 = newEmployee;
  this.Name = 'jim';
  this.Phone = '555-5552';
  document.write(Employee.name Employee.phone);

  var emp3 = newEmployee;
  this.Name = 'jon';
  this.Phone = '555-5553';
  document.write(Employee.name Employee.phone);
```

Comment: There's a lot of errors in your code, I would suggest using the javascript console on your browser to first look at what errors it spits out and fix those first.

Comment: there need to be spaces between `new` and `Employee`. You forgot an `e` in the constructor function's name. Need I continue? What did you say? I do need to continue? Ok then. You put `var = name` where you should actually be putting `this.name=''`. You forgot parenthesis after `new Employee`. You are inefficiently adding name and phone numbers to the objects where you should have arguments to the constructor. You are making absolutely useless functions `setName` and `getName`. I would say much, much more but I'm running out of characters...

Comment: oh, I forgot, you also are doing `this.name` where you should be doing `emp1.name`

Answer (score 0):

In the following:

```
> var emp1 = newEmployee;
```

The variable on the left will be assigned the result of evaluating the expression on the right. There is no identifier `newEmployee`, so you will get an error. What you probably meant to write is:

```
var emp1 = new Employee();
```

That will call the constructor, which will return a new instance, a reference to which will be assigned to *emp1*.

Then you have:

```
>  this.Name = 'jo';
```

The value of *this* is set when entering an execution context. For global code, it always references the global object (which is equivalent to *window* in a browser). So the above line creates a *Name* property of the global object and assigns the value 'jo';

What you wanted is probably:

```
emp1.setName('jo','555-5551');
```

The name of that method seems inappropriate given that it sets both the name and phone number.

```
> document.write(Employee.name Employee.phone);
```

Since you added the properties to the instance (emp1), likely that's the properties you want to read:

```
document.write(emp1.name + ' ' + emp1.phone);
```

or to use the *getName* method:

```
document.write(emp1.getName() + ' ' + emp1.phone);
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot wrong with your code example. The constructor is misspelled. The employee instances should be created like:

var emp1 = new Employee();

The instance properties should be set like:

emp1.setName('John');

You've also combined two setters into one, which is confusing.

To access the instance properties, you should use:

emp1.getName();

Not:

Employee.Name

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have a lot of errors I think this is basically what you want to achieve.

```
  function Employee(){
this.name;
this.phone;
this.getName = function(){
return this.name;
};
this.setName = function(name, phone){
 this.name = name;
 this.phone = phone;
 };
}

function employ(){

  var emp1 = new Employee();
  emp1.name = 'jo';
  emp1.phone = ' 555-5551' ; 

   alert(emp1.getName());
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/umNTs/